# UASP requirements: does the HD need to support UASP?

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-storage, usb-3, uasp

According to [this article](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/usb-3-uas-turbo,3215-4.html), these are the requirements to have UASP enabled:

1. UAS support in the USB driver stack.
2. Device hardware supporting UAS.
3. Device firmware supporting UAS.
4. UAS-compatible system controller.

I have a very new laptop (Skylake) running Windows 10 (1607).

The [USB 3.0 adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OFJ1UK6) used supports UASP (JMicron JMS567 chipset).

When plugged in, the driver used for the disk (2.5 Seagate HD, and older 500gb drive) is "USB Attached SCSI (UAS) Mass Storage Device". There are no updates for this driver from MS (current version). There are no firmware updates for this drive from Seagate.

Even with the information from the article above, I still don't know: **does the disk need to support UASP?** *Device* in the article could be the host, the adapter or the disk, AFAIK.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything,including installing drivers, in order to achieve, USB 3.0 speeds.  So if you were not getting them it means your drive isn't a  USB 3.0 device which is requirement 2 and 3.

Comment: @Ramhound the question is not about USB 3.0. UASP can be active even over USB 2.0. The drive is never USB 2.0 or 3.0 either - that's a feature of the SATA to USB adapter and the host.

Comment: I know all of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disk doesn't care about USAP or not. This is a feature of the chipset of the SATA/USB converter.

Only for slow HDDs it makes no difference is USAP is used or not. The drive is simply too slow.

It only makes sense for SATA3 SSDs with speeds larger 250MB/s like my older Samsung 830 SSD.

Without UASP the speed is limited to 250MB/s due to USB Mass Storage Bulk-Only Transport (BOT)

[image]

With UASP the speed is over 400MB/s

[image]

Comment: Thx, that answers it. Keep in mind there is less processor usage on UASP vs BOT, even if you don't achieve a higher transfer rate via UASP.

Comment: [Burst speed](https://www.overclock.net/threads/hd-tune-burst-rate.634834/) of the fastest HDDs can still [take a hit](https://web.archive.org/web/20100118171201/http://techreport.com/articles.x/18077/2) without UASP (and on top of that, I guess like NCQ is [important](https://www.anandtech.com/show/1657/8) whenever you aren't just doing big stupid sequential copies).

Comment: Coming to this late, but UASP is important in a USB disk enclosure where you're using multiple disks maybe striped or mirrored by the operating system. UASP (SCSI) allows multiple operations to be carried out at once whereas BOT is sequential